# Can't send requests from frontend to my laravel beckend because of CORS

Tags: laravel, cors, laravel-6

i have a strange problem.
I am using laravel as my beckend and from the frontend i am trying to send a request to my API, but it is on another server, so i used [laravel-cors](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) for CORS.

But i am still getting `Has been blocked by CORS POLICY no access controll allow origin problem`.

How may i solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your frontend  build on ??

Comment: Have you added `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class` to the middleware array?

Comment: @SyedAbdurRehmanKazmi react

Comment: @UrošAnđelić yes

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this two lines to your public/index.php file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Or..
In a Laravel way using middleware you can create a middleware name cors:

```
php artisan make:middleware Cors
```

Then  put this code in the handle method:

```
return $next($request)
      ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’, ‘*’)
      ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods’, ‘GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS’)
      ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’, ‘X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization’);
```

Add this line to your $routeMiddleware variable in app/http/kernel.php file:

```
‘cors’ => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

And then use this middleware on your routes:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v.1', 'namespace' => 'API', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
// routes...
});
```

Comment: Shojai 
this is not working :((((((